# How to communicate QThread with my Widgets from main class

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

My app is freezing because i need to create a new QThread, but am a little confused how to create it when i call widgets that exists on the main class.

here is my code so far ...

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
import time

##Main Class
class HWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super(HWindow, self).__init__()
        loadUi("Hw.ui",self) ##load ui

        #Create a QThread object
        self.thread = QtCore.QThread()
        #Create a QThread object
        self.workerMain = WorkerMain()
        #Move worker to the thread
        self.workerMain.moveToThread(self.thread)
        #Start the thread
        self.thread.start()
        self.runningMain = False


    def activateMain(self):
        if self.chkb_main.isChecked():
            self.lbl_disena_main.setText("Activated")
            self.lbl_disena_main.setStyleSheet('color: green;')
            #Change variable and call the function
            runningMain = True 
            self.myFunction()            
        else:
            self.lbl_disena_main.setText("Disabled")
            self.lbl_disena_main.setStyleSheet('color: red;')
            #Change variable and call the function
            runningMain = False 

    def myFunction(self):
        while self.runningMain == True:
            if self.gpb_main.isChecked() and self.chkb_main.isChecked():
                print("running ...")
                time.sleep(3)

##Worker Class
class WorkerMain(QtCore.QObject):
    threadRunning = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super(WorkerMain, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        print("Thread Running ...")

        #i cant call my widgets from my main class from here.
        '''
        while self.runningMain == True:
            if self.gpb_main.isChecked() and self.chkb_main.isChecked():
                print("running ...")
                time.sleep(3)
        '''

    def stop(self):
        print("Thread Stopped ...")
        self.terminate()
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    hWindow = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    hWindow = HWindow()  
    hWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Based on pyqt5 documentation and examples, you create a loop on the run method, but it is complicated when i have to create that loop based on what the user select (GUI widgets).

Comment: Your code is very confusing. Also, if you call `self.myFunction()` you're doing *both* the things that shall never be done in the UI thread and the reason for which threading is used: a while loop, and a `time.sleep`. Not to mention that the `runningMain = ...` in `activateMain` is completely useless, since you're setting a local variable. It *seems* that you want to run a loop in the thread depending on the fact that a button is checked or not, but I'm not completely sure due to the confusing code.

Comment: Hi @musicamante, I want to run the thread depending if the button is checked or not. my code is confusing and a lot of it useless cause I couldn't make it work, i just don't know how to check my button inside the loop on the thread. Also appreciate your comments tho, about the things that i should never do.

Comment: Hi @musicamante, any advice on how to run a loop in the thread depending on the fact that a button is checked or not?, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just figure it out, here is my code ...

```
class HWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super(HWindow, self).__init__()
        loadUi("Hw.ui",self) ##load ui

        #Create a QThread object
        self.thread = QtCore.QThread()
        #Create a QThread object
        self.workerMain = WorkerMain(self)
        #Move worker to the thread
        self.workerMain.moveToThread(self.thread)
        #Connect the start signal to the run slot
        self.workerMain.threadRunning.connect(self.workerMain.run)
        #Connect the activateMain signal to the start slot
        self.chkb_main.toggled.connect(self.activateMain)
        #Start the thread
        self.thread.start()


    def activateMain(self):
        if self.chkb_main.isChecked():
            self.lbl_disena_main.setText("Activated")
            self.lbl_disena_main.setStyleSheet('color: green;')
            self.workerMain.runningMain = True
            self.workerMain.threadRunning.emit()
            if not self.thread.isRunning():
                self.thread.start()          
        else:
            self.lbl_disena_main.setText("Disabled")
            self.lbl_disena_main.setStyleSheet('color: red;')
            self.workerMain.runningMain = False
            self.workerMain.stop()


##Worker Class
class WorkerMain(QtCore.QObject):
    threadRunning = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(WorkerMain, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        self.runningMain = False

    def run(self):
        print("Thread Running ...")
        while self.runningMain:
            if self.parent.gpb_main.isChecked() and self.parent.chkb_main.isChecked():
                print("running ...")
                time.sleep(3)

    def stop(self):
        print("Thread Stopped ...")
        if self.parent.thread.isRunning():
            self.parent.thread.quit()
            self.parent.thread.wait()
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    hWindow = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    hWindow = HWindow()  
    hWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```